# Can't understand how insert data in list from adapter

Tags: java, android, android-listview, custom-adapter

I have a custom adapter:

```
public class SoluzioniAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String>{

//riferimenti statici alle risorse e agli id
private final static int LAYOUT = R.layout.riga_soluzioni;
private final static int PARTENZA = R.id.partenza;
private final static int ARRIVO = R.id.arrivo;
private final static int DATA = R.id.data;
ArrayList<String> partenze; //lista delle partenze
ArrayList<String> arrivi; //lista degli arrivi
ArrayList<String> date; //lista delle date

Context c; //context
LayoutInflater inflater; //layout inflater

public SoluzioniAdapter(Context context,ArrayList<String> partenze,ArrayList<String> arrivi,ArrayList<String> date )
{
super(context,PARTENZA);
this.c = context;
this.partenze = partenze;
this.arrivi = arrivi;
this.date = date;
this.inflater = LayoutInflater.from(c);
}

@Override
public int getCount()
{
return partenze.size(); //ritorno lunghezza lista ( = numero dei titoli)
}

//quando la lista richiede una view
@Override
public View getView(int pos,View view,ViewGroup parent)
{
CacheRiga cache; //cache
if(view==null)//se è la prima volta che viene richiesta la view
{
// creo la view ma non l'attacco alla lista in quanto devo ancora modificare
// i testi delle textview
view = inflater.inflate(LAYOUT, parent,false); 
cache = new CacheRiga(); //inizializzo la cache
cache.partenza = (TextView) view.findViewById(PARTENZA); //collego titolo
cache.arrivo = (TextView) view.findViewById(ARRIVO);//collego descrizione
cache.data = (TextView) view.findViewById(DATA);//collego descrizione
view.setTag(cache);//collego view con cache
}
else
{
cache = (CacheRiga) view.getTag(); //altrimenti prendo la cache dalla view
}

cache.partenza.setText(partenze.get(pos)); //imposto il titolo
cache.arrivo.setText(arrivi.get(pos)); // e la descrizione
cache.data.setText(date.get(pos)); // e la descrizione

return view;
}

private class CacheRiga { // classe per la cache delle righe
public TextView partenza; // cache titolo
public TextView arrivo; // cache descrizione
public TextView data; // cache descrizione
}

}
```

I have pass `partenza`,`arrivo` and `data` at my list.

```
private static class SoluzioniLoader extends AsyncTaskLoader<List<Soluzione>> {

    private FermataComune partenza;
    private FermataComune arrivo;
    private String data;

    public SoluzioniLoader(Context context, FermataComune partenza, FermataComune arrivo, String data) {
      super(context);
      this.partenza = partenza;
      this.arrivo = arrivo;
      this.data = data;
    }

    @Override
    public List<Soluzione> loadInBackground() {

    try {

      List<Soluzione> soluzioni = Client.cercaCorseAndata(partenza, arrivo, data);
      return soluzioni;
    } catch (IOException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
      return null;
    }

    }
}

private LoaderCallbacks<List<Soluzione>> mLoaderCallbacks = new LoaderCallbacks<List<Soluzione>>() {
    private ProgressDialog pd;
    @Override
    public Loader<List<Soluzione>> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args) {
    pd = new ProgressDialog(SoluzioniActivity.this);
    pd.setTitle("Caricamento Soluzioni Trovate");
    pd.setMessage("Attendi...");
    pd.setIndeterminate(false);
    pd.show();

    return new SoluzioniLoader(SoluzioniActivity.this, partenza, arrivo, data);
}

@Override
public void onLoadFinished(Loader<List<Soluzione>> loader, List<Soluzione> data) {
    try {
    pd.dismiss();
     } catch(Exception e){  
    }

    if (data == null) {
    // ERRORE
    } else {
    SoluzioniAdapter adapter = new SoluzioniAdapter(SoluzioniActivity.this, partenze, arrivi, date);
mListView.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

and of course it doesn't work. I think because the array it's empty.. And i can't understand  what i have to do right now. Thanks

Comment: Sorry, but you can't just dump a bunch of code on SO, say "It doesn't work", and expect us to magically fix it.  You'll need to narrow down the problem, and then tell us specifically what's wrong.  For example, you say "I think because the array it's empty", but you didn't tell us whether it's an error that the array is empty, or whether an empty array is a normal situation that your program isn't handling right.  If you're not sure whether your variables have the right values in them, use a debugger or the `Log` methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this sectcion you are using the adapter, but I don't see when you are filling "partenze", "arrivi" and "date".

```
@Override
public void onLoadFinished(Loader<List<Soluzione>> loader, List<Soluzione> data) {
    try {
    pd.dismiss();
     } catch(Exception e){  
    }

    if (data == null) {
    // ERRORE
    } else {
    SoluzioniAdapter adapter = new SoluzioniAdapter(SoluzioniActivity.this, partenze, arrivi, date);
mListView.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

I think those values are inside this `List<Soluzione> soluzioni` but you haver tu put the values in the other three arrays or maybe pass only the array of `Soluzione` in the adapter

Comment: Yes Soluzione contains an ArrayList called Corsa. Corsa is a class with the objects i pass.

Comment: can you help me to solve? i think the way is pass the array Soluzione in the adapter but i can't understand how do it.

Comment: @End.Game can you post the Soluzione class, to see how to make it works?

Comment: I solved some minutes ago :) thanks anyway. I accept your answer because that was the problem.